# Count the number of recursive calls Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, char

So I'm a little new to Java and am currently taking a CS intro class at uni. I have a little question that's been bugging me for quite a while. I have a to write a recursive method that "decompresses" the input text using the a "Run-length encoding (RLE)" algorithm. Simply put, if the input is "qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT" the output has to be "q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T". Currently, my method decomposes the input to just one letter without the numbers (qwertyqwErT).

My question is how can I actually count the number of letters *recursively*? I'm not allowed to declare any variables outside the method and that's my main problem, as all the problems I've searched on Stackoverflow mostly use a "global variable". However, I am allowed to declare as many local variables as I want.

The professor also gave us a "hint":

Hint #1: remember that characters are represented by numeric codes. You can decrement a character variable as follows:

char c = '7';
c--;           // c will now hold the character '6'

I tried to work with this by adding a numbered character at the end of the input I'm working with and incrementing it every single time there's a duplicate character and then replacing it to the front when there's a new character, but that hasn't been working either.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I should probably include the fact that I'm not allowed to use any loops of any kind AND that I could assume that a character will not repeat itself more than (9) times

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the return value of the recursive function call to return the compressed string, you could create another parameter to keep track of how many times the function has been called. By using a reference variable it can act as a sort of "global variable" for that method call.

```
public String compress(..., Integer callCount) 
{
    callCount++;

    ...
}
```

Then do something like this from your calling function

```
Integer callCount;
compress(..., callCount);
System.out.println("Compressed in " + callCount + " iterations");
```

Of course, since you need the value within the function itself to add the number of times a character is repeated there is nothing stopping you from using `callCount` in the function as well.

The other option would be to use a static variable, which is similar to the approach of using a global.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are indeed a thing to avoid. Fortunately, you totally don't need them to implement a pure function which is RLE compression.

The hint allows you to use digits (characters) as counters directly. Consider this fragment:

```
char c = getNextChar();
if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
  counter = c;
  char_to_decompress = getNextChar();
  while (c > '0') {
    result.add(char_to_decompress);
    c--; // the 'trick'
  } 
}
```

This, of course, only works if there are no runs longer than 9 characters.

WRT recursion, I don't see a nice way to use it except to replace the outer loop. (Anything that can be expressed with recursion can be expressed with a loop, and vice versa.)

```
String decompress(String input) {
  if (input == '') return ''; // this stops recursion
  int position = 0; // where have we advanced
  String result = '';
  if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(position))) {
    position += 1;
    // ... decompress input.charAt(position) into result
  } 
  else {
    result = input.charAt(position); // not compressed
  }
  // here come recursion
  return result + decompress(input.substring(position + 1)); 
}
```

This is, of course, not what a seasoned Java developer would do, because cutting and adding strings is pretty slow, you have to use a `StringBuffer` to collect the result and a `CharSequence` as input to allow cheap string slicing.

But the general idea is still there. This algorithm would look much nicer in a language where strings are lists, and cutting a list's head is a natural operation, and recursion is the basic way to express loops. When / if you come to know a language like Lisp or Haskell or Erlang, you'll see the point clearer.

Comment: Input string contains no digits.